# I'm able to access a private method in a children model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Trying to do Single Table Inheritance using Rails 5.0.0.1(latest), and if you do:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  private
  def self.some_method=(argument)
    return true
  end
end

class Child < Parent
end

$ rails console
irb(main):001:0> Client.some_method
=> true
```

The code will works, which is not what I expected, it should work only if is
protected. Could anyone explain why this code is working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks but adding `private_class_method` to parent class did not worked.
any other suggestion?

Comment: It works for me. `NoMethodError: private method `some_method' called for Child:Class
from (pry):1:in `<main>'`